# How do you make Jquery UI Button to have 32x32 px non-default icons?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to use my own 32 x 32 px icons in a Jquery Button? 
Is this possible?
I can make it work using forcing the background-size of the icon to 16x16 but then is too small.

```
.ui-icon-custom-risk { background-size:16px 16px; background-image: url(icons/Current_Risk.png) !important; }
.ui-icon-custom-matrix { background-size:32px 32px;; background-image: url(icons/Current_matrix.png) !important; } 
$('#btn1').button({
   label: 'Risk',
   icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-custom-risk'}
});
$('#btn2').button({
    text: false,
    icons: {
         primary: "ui-icon-custom-matrix"  
    }
});
```

Comment: double ; after 32px ? is that right?